# Finite ordinal Exponentiation

Tags: ordinals

I confused a little when i do arithmetic on ordinals especially multiplication
is what i wrote right? :

> $(ω+1)$ = {$0,1,....ω$}

> $(ω+1)(ω+1)$ = sup({lexicographic Order($(ω+1)×(ω+1)$)}) = $ω²+1$

> $(ω+1)(ω+1)(ω+1)$ = sup({lexicographic Order($(ω+1)×(ω+1)×(ω+1)$)})= $ω³+1$

> $(ω+1)ⁿ$ = $ωⁿ+1$

and

> $(ω+k)ⁿ$ = $ωⁿ+k$

Im sorry for asking it because i couldn't find any library for python or website to check my calculation is right or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinal multiplication has the property that $\alpha\cdot(\beta+1)=(\alpha\cdot\beta)+\alpha$ for all ordinals $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so

$$(\omega+1)\cdot(\omega+1)=\big((\omega+1)\cdot\omega\big)+(\omega+1)\;;$$

and $(\omega+1)\cdot\omega=\omega^2$, so $(\omega+1)\cdot(\omega+1)=\omega^2+\omega+1\ne\omega^2+1$.

Then

$$\begin{align*}
(\omega+1)^3&=(\omega+1)^2\cdot(\omega+1)\\
&=(\omega^2+\omega+1)\cdot(\omega+1)\\
&=(\omega^2+\omega+1)\cdot\omega+\omega^2+\omega+1)\\
&=\omega^3+\omega^2+\omega+1\;.
\end{align*}$$

Can you correct the rest of it from here?

Comment: Yes I can. Thanks 

Comment: @OmidYaghoubi: You’re welcome.